# flashfirebug getting data from actionscript 3 console

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, firebug

My need was to capture data (text data) from flash in a web page. 
The data is always changing (wheather data) and this should be exported do a text file so i could manipulate this data.

I tried do this with and my first approach was using a websniffer like fiddler or wireshark.
I used that but could't get data from both because it is embedded in flash.
I used fidler as man-in-midle with wireshark deciphering the data (with the private key from the site cer) but it didn't worked.

After that i tried using flashfirebug pro (the pro allows to run as3 comands in the console). This addon loads the dom tree and refreshes it. After selecting in the page the desired element with inspector (it shows in the left panel the instance and position in the dom) i have acess to the instance properties (and the only one needed is the "html-text" in the right panel).

My problem with this last approach was that it could not communicate with the local file system (if i make "trace(this.text);"  in the console it shows the text value but it just shows in the console). The only way to communicate to the file in the hard drive, that i could think of was to throw some error to the log file but could't do that also.

Does anyone have any idea to work with flashfirebug or have some other approach to do this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work on local filesystems use adobe air.
if you can't, try to work around the browsers sandbox with javascript as bridge to some browser-plugin/-addon which gives you access to local processes and filesystems. to use javascript from flash the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class is your friend.

Comment: thanks it works, i have been there some time ago but now got deeper and can communicate between javascript to flash addon, but unfortuntly the opposite was needed too and cant get it to work. will post another topic to callback function from flash to firebug console. :P